# PayPal net refund calculation

Tags: php, paypal, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the net refund amount. This is the situation:

PayPal returns (within 180 days) the fee of the percentage refunded. Now because PayPal substracts the fee from the refunded amount i want to calculate how to refund a net amount.

Easy explaind:

- The refund is € 18,-
- Original amount was € 25,-
- PayPal fee was € 1,-

Now if i refund € 18,- PayPal will refund:

"refund amount" - (("fee" - "PayPal not refundable fee") * ("refund amount" / "orginal amount")) = "refunded amount"

€ 18 - (( € 1 - € 0,35 ) * (€ 18 / € 25)) = € 17,53.

But I want to refund € 18,-. If i make the amount € 18,49 it would refund € 18,- (what i want). But I just can't figure out what the calculation would be to calculate the € 18,49.

18,49 - (( 1 - 0,35 ) * (18,49 / 25)) = € 18,-

Answer (score 0):

I recalculated my own question and it was wrong. Sorry.. But i found the solution, i will show it with a real (tested) example:

**Payed amount (inc. fee):** € 269,76

**Fee payed:** € 8,17 (- € 0,35 = € 7,82)

**Amount to return:** € 150,-

( € 7,82 / € 269,76 ) * 100 = 2,9 % fee

**Important calculation:** € 150 / ( 1 - 2,9 %) = € 154,48

*(€ 4,48 will be substracted of the refunded amount so the amount to refund is exactly € 150,-)*